# COUNTIF function for documents in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, aggregation

My problem involves mongodb and pymongo; I have a db with multiple collections. Each collection has thousands of documents in it, but most only contain about 10-200 "unique" documents. I would like to COUNTIF how many times each "unique" document occurs in a specific collection. I have seen examples of COUNTIFS with specific field values, but not counting entire documents.

I've been reading a fair bit about aggregations, but I still don't know if I'm on the right track; would appreciate some guidance.

Assuming there were 20 total documents in the collection, but only 3 are unique. I want to output COUNTIF values similar to this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cde2f68416437c1ae98de18"), "Source Network Address LP" : [ "192.168.5.5" ], "Account Name" : [ " -", " ANONYMOUS LOGON" ], "Process Name LP" : [ "-" ] } - 10
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cde2f68416437c1ae98de19"), "Source Network Address LP" : [ "192.168.5.8" ], "Account Name" : [ " -", " ANONYMOUS LOGON" ], "Process Name LP" : [ "-" ] } - 6
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cde2f68416437c1ae98de19"), "Source Network Address LP" : [ "192.168.5.2" ], "Account Name" : [ " -", " ANONYMOUS LOGON" ], "Process Name LP" : [ "-" ] } - 4
```

Eventually I'll write this output to a CSV file in the following format:

```
Source Network Address,Account Name,Process Name LP,count
'192.168.5.5','-|ANONYMOUS LOGON','-',10
'192.168.5.8','-|ANONYMOUS LOGON','-',6
'192.168.5.2','-|ANONYMOUS LOGON','-',4
```

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a solution to my problem, but did not filter / count using pymongo. Instead, I simply iterated over db.collection.find() output and used collections.Counter() with python-box (https://pypi.org/project/python-box/). It is impossible to use collections.Counter() with a normal built-in Python dict because dictionaries are not hashable. You can, however, use a frozen python-box Box() object to create a hashable dict, then count using collections.Counter().

I did run into a slight issue while counting at first because even if documents were almost entirely identical, they were never exactly identical because of the unique _id field.

```
for doc in db.collections.find():
    dict_record = dict(doc)
    del(dict_doc['_id'])
    # Box object makes dict object hashable so we can count
    b = Box(dict_doc, frozen_box=True)
    stacked[b] += 1
```

If someone comes up with a solution for filtering & counting purely using pymongo then please let me know; I am curious.